# iPhone OS create bundle with private data

Tags: iphone, static, bundles

I am in the situation where i need to create a toolkit for iphone apps. I know that i am not allowed to create frameworks with code + xib files + images, but i am allowed to use static libraries.
So what i have done is to compile my code into a static library, and now i have to create a bundle with a lot of images and xib files for my toolkit. 
The problem is that i need to hide this images and xib files but inside bundles everything is open to everyone. I know that you can't include xib files inside static libraries but i am wondering how should this be done, there should be some kind of way to distribute my toolkit without exposing my external data.
Thanks